# Como fazer replace de string usando uma outra string contendo Json?

Tags: c#, replace

Existe alguma forma de fazer um replace de uma String com os campo de uma outra string que contém um Json?

Exemplo;

Tenho a string;

```
String template = "Olá [Nome], Tenha um bom dia ... hoje é [Data] e é seu aniversario";
```

E na outra string teria;

```
String mensagem = "{"Nome": "Marconcilio","Data": "21/01/18"}"
```

Sendo que na minha string  **template** os *[Nome]* e *[Data]*, são variáveis, ou seja em um determinado momento pode conter um outro dado como [Senha], mas sempre que isso acontece vai ter um respectivo campo na string que tem o Json (mensagem).

Em fim o resultado seria.

```
String conteudo = "Olá Marconcilio, Tenha um bom dia ... hoje é 21/01/18 e é seu aniversario";
```

Comment: que tal usando regex?

Comment: @Paz, tem como fazer isso com regex ? e fazer o replece do valor que contem no Json ?

Comment: Acredito que sim, só me confirma se o valor em mensagem está correto e se estiver, se poderia ser modificado.

Comment: Você quer que tudo seja dinâmico? Só tendo a string "template" e o JSON?

Comment: @LINQ, isso mesmo.. no templete tenho os campos que estão no json.. e quero substituir pelo valor da propriedade do Json.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode deserializar o JSON em um dicionário e depois iterar sobre este dicionário para fazer as substituições na *string* de *template*.

Note que no meu exemplo, eu uso o pacote [NewstonSoft.Json](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) para deserializar o JSON com as respostas. Isso não é necessário, você pode usar qualquer outro serializador, eu escolhi este por costume. Isso não faz nenhuma diferença na ideia principal.

```
string Transformar(string template, string json)
{
    var dict = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(json); 

    string nova = template;
    foreach(var par in dict)
    {
        nova = nova.Replace($"[{par.Key}]", par.Value);
    }

    return nova;
}

void Main()
{
    string json = "{\"Nome\": \"Marconcilio\", \"Data\": \"21/01/18\"}";
    string template = "Olá [Nome], Tenha um bom dia ... hoje é [Data] e é seu aniversario";

    Console.WriteLine(template);
    // Olá [Nome], Tenha um bom dia ... hoje é [Data] e é seu aniversario
    Console.WriteLine(Transformar(template, json));
    // Olá Marconcilio, Tenha um bom dia ... hoje é 21/01/18 e é seu aniversario
}
```

<sup>[**Veja funcionando no .NET Fiddle.**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/JkhkTt)</sup>

Fiz "marconcilio" uma alteração para object de navegação no json.

```
string Transformar(string template, string json)
{
    var dict = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<object, object>>(json); 


    string nova = template;
    foreach(var par in dict)
    {
        if(par.Value.ToString().Contains ("{"))
        {
            nova = Transformar(nova, par.Value.ToString());
        }

      nova = nova.Replace(string.Format("[{0}]", par.Key), par.Value.ToString());
    }

    return nova;
}

public void Main()
{
    string json = "{ \"Nome\": \"Marconcilio\",\"destinatarioDaNotificacao\": {\"Data\": 11},\"Notificacao\": {\"Teste\": \"novo\"}}";
    string template = "Olá [Nome], Tenha um bom dia ... hoje é [Data] e é seu aniversario .. [Teste]";

    Console.WriteLine(template);
    Console.WriteLine(Transformar(template, json));
}
```

Comment: qual using é necessário para o JsonConvert funcionar?

Comment: @Paz Acho que a minha edição já responde isto

Comment: Alterei sua resposta com uma alteração que precisava.